# GCC warning when using CAPI calling convention

Tags: haskell, ghc, ffi

When using CAPI like this:

```
// libvlc.h
libvlc_instance_t *libvlc_new (int argc, const char *const *argv)

// VLC.hs
foreign import capi "vlc/libvlc.h libvlc_new" vlcNew :: CInt -> Ptr CString -> IO (Ptr Libvlc)
```

I'm getting the warning

```
/tmp/ghc3011_0/ghc3011_0.c: In function ‘ghc_wrapper_d18b_libvlc_new’:

/tmp/ghc3011_0/ghc3011_0.c:10:1:
     warning: passing argument 2 of ‘libvlc_new’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

In file included from /tmp/ghc3011_0/ghc3011_0.c:7:0: 

/usr/include/vlc/libvlc.h:138:1:
     note: expected ‘const char * const*’ but argument is of type ‘HsInt8 **’
```

Compiles cleanly when using `ccall`.

It seems to be fine, but it's still a warning. Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: `argv` is a `const char *const *`, an array of C strings, not a single C string.

Comment: Fixed, but the problem remains.

Comment: Maybe a GHC bug? I wonder what the differences between the generated temp C files are with `ccall` vs `capi`? You can pass `-keep-temp-files` to `ghc` to find out.